# Wifi service stops randomy

Tags: wifi, networking

Elementary 5.1 Hera
NetworkManager v 1.10.6
Lenovo Yoga 13 inch, Intel i5

My NetworkManager randomly drops wifi communications.  Wifi signal strength drops to around 50% but a connection is indicated but there nothing loads into a browser, Firefox v 71.0 in this case.

Tried turning off power management but no joy.

Wifi adapter is RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac. I installed the latest driver but again no joy.

I noticed from the journalctl output that NetworkManager is unable to open /run/network/ifstate because that directory and file does not exist on my system.

I have a persistent USB version of Zorin which does not have the same or similar issue.  I noted that Zorin does have /run/network/ifstate installed.

Does anyone have a permanent solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same adapter (in a Lenovo Legion Y530) and I had to turn [aspm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_State_Power_Management) off for the wireless adapter.

Create a new `r8822be.conf` file in `/etc/modprobe.d/`, with the following contents:
`options r8822be aspm=0`
After this, I also had to turn off the laptop, unplug the charger, wait for a few minutes, and turn it back on. No more wireless issues after this.

Comment: I tried this suggestion but it did not produce an improvement in stability.